# How to add mouse drag function to double pendulum

Tags: java, processing

I have code for a double pendulum that traces the second pendulums centre with a line by using the previous position of the pendulum. I need to add a function  that when the mouse is clicked (on or not on the pendulum, it doesnt matter), the pendulum can be dragged around the screen within the boundaries of the pendulum, im not sure if mouse dragged() would work or if i should use a class for the pendulum to make it easier

```
float r1 = 200;
float r2 = 200;
float m1 = 40;
float m2 = 40;
float a1 = PI/2;
float a2 = PI/2;
float a1_v = 0;
float a2_v = 0;
float g = 1;

float px2 = -1;
float py2 = -1;
float cx, cy;

PGraphics canvas;

void setup() {
  size(900, 600);
  cx = width/2;
  cy = 200;
  canvas = createGraphics(width, height);
  canvas.beginDraw();
  canvas.background(255);
  canvas.endDraw();
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  imageMode(CORNER);
  image(canvas, 0, 0, width, height);

  float num1 = -g * (2 * m1 + m2) * sin(a1);
  float num2 = -m2 * g * sin(a1-2*a2);
  float num3 = -2*sin(a1-a2)*m2;
  float num4 = a2_v*a2_v*r2+a1_v*a1_v*r1*cos(a1-a2);
  float den = r1 * (2*m1+m2-m2*cos(2*a1-2*a2));
  float a1_a = (num1 + num2 + num3*num4) / den;

  num1 = 2 * sin(a1-a2);
  num2 = (a1_v*a1_v*r1*(m1+m2));
  num3 = g * (m1 + m2) * cos(a1);
  num4 = a2_v*a2_v*r2*m2*cos(a1-a2);
  den = r2 * (2*m1+m2-m2*cos(2*a1-2*a2));
  float a2_a = (num1*(num2+num3+num4)) / den;

  translate(cx, cy);
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(2);

  float x1 = r1 * sin(a1);
  float y1 = r1 * cos(a1);

  float x2 = x1 + r2 * sin(a2);
  float y2 = y1 + r2 * cos(a2);


  line(0, 0, x1, y1);
  fill(0);
  ellipse(x1, y1, m1, m1);

  line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  fill(0);
  ellipse(x2, y2, m2, m2);

  a1_v += a1_a;
  a2_v += a2_a;
  a1 += a1_v;
  a2 += a2_v;

  // a1_v *= 0.99;
  // a2_v *= 0.99;

  canvas.beginDraw();
  //canvas.background(0, 1);
  canvas.translate(cx, cy);
  canvas.stroke(0);
  if (frameCount > 1) {
    canvas.line(px2, py2, x2, y2);
  }
  canvas.endDraw();


  px2 = x2;
  py2 = y2;
}
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 oh, sorry! My bad.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track: `cx` and `cy` are the coordinates of the system's origin.

Simply update those to the mouse coordinates in the `mouseDragged()` callback:

```
void mouseDragged(){
  cx = mouseX;
  cy = mouseY;
}
```

To address your question as clarified in the comments, one quick and dirty option is to simply override x2,y2 with mouse coordinates (offsetting by the `cx,cy` system origin position):

```
float x2 = 0;
  float y2 = 0;

  if(mousePressed){
    x2 = mouseX - cx;
    y2 = mouseY - cy;
  }else{
    x2 = x1 + r2 * sin(a2);
    y2 = y1 + r2 * cos(a2);  
  }
```

here's a full code listing with the above applied:

```
float r1 = 200;
float r2 = 200;
float m1 = 40;
float m2 = 40;
float a1 = PI/2;
float a2 = PI/2;
float a1_v = 0;
float a2_v = 0;
float g = 1;

float px2 = -1;
float py2 = -1;
float cx, cy;

PGraphics canvas;

void setup() {
  size(900, 600);
  cx = width/2;
  cy = 200;
  canvas = createGraphics(width, height);
  canvas.beginDraw();
  canvas.background(255);
  canvas.endDraw();
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  imageMode(CORNER);
  image(canvas, 0, 0, width, height);

  float num1 = -g * (2 * m1 + m2) * sin(a1);
  float num2 = -m2 * g * sin(a1-2*a2);
  float num3 = -2*sin(a1-a2)*m2;
  float num4 = a2_v*a2_v*r2+a1_v*a1_v*r1*cos(a1-a2);
  float den = r1 * (2*m1+m2-m2*cos(2*a1-2*a2));
  float a1_a = (num1 + num2 + num3*num4) / den;

  num1 = 2 * sin(a1-a2);
  num2 = (a1_v*a1_v*r1*(m1+m2));
  num3 = g * (m1 + m2) * cos(a1);
  num4 = a2_v*a2_v*r2*m2*cos(a1-a2);
  den = r2 * (2*m1+m2-m2*cos(2*a1-2*a2));
  float a2_a = (num1*(num2+num3+num4)) / den;

  translate(cx, cy);
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(2);

  float x1 = r1 * sin(a1);
  float y1 = r1 * cos(a1);

  float x2 = 0;
  float y2 = 0;

  if(mousePressed){
    x2 = mouseX - cx;
    y2 = mouseY - cy;
  }else{
    x2 = x1 + r2 * sin(a2);
    y2 = y1 + r2 * cos(a2);  
  }

  line(0, 0, x1, y1);
  fill(0);
  ellipse(x1, y1, m1, m1);

  line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  fill(0);
  ellipse(x2, y2, m2, m2);

  a1_v += a1_a;
  a2_v += a2_a;
  a1 += a1_v;
  a2 += a2_v;

  // a1_v *= 0.99;
  // a2_v *= 0.99;

  canvas.beginDraw();
  //canvas.background(0, 1);
  canvas.translate(cx, cy);
  canvas.stroke(0);
  if (frameCount > 1) {
    canvas.line(px2, py2, x2, y2);
  }
  canvas.endDraw();


  px2 = x2;
  py2 = y2;
}
```

Bare in mind this will simply allow you to drag the second ball visually, completely ignoring the simulation. When you release the mouse the simulation will resume. If you do want to affect the simulation from bottom to top you will need to workout the math (lines 32-44 in your case).

Comment: This moves the starting point of the pendulum, i need the second pendulum to move with the mouse, ive tried using the x2 and y2 variables because they are the center of the second pendulum but it doesnt work, should i add another variable that does nothing but keeps track of the centre and use that?

Comment: Interesting ! The way your question is phrased reads (at least to me) as you want to drag the whole pendulum with a mouse (within screen bounds). Do you plan to drag the first ellipse (driven by `x1`,`y1` variables) or the second ellipse (driven by `x2`,`y2` variables) ? When you say "the second pendulum to move with the mouse" do you mean dragging the origin/top of the pendulum or the bottom of the pendulum ?

Comment: "the second ellipse (driven by x2,y2 variables)" the function you gave previously worked perfectly just not on the part i need it to.

Comment: The bottom of the pendulum needs to move with the mouse on click within the bounds of the pendulum and screen (full circle for pendulum and screen resolution) im not bothered by clicking directly on the circle as long as its on the screen so mousedragged{} should be fine