# How to create gravity function on mousepress()?

Tags: processing

I need to make the mousePressed() function act as a source of gravity and impact the rest of the double pendulum.

Ideally it will "push" the pendulum circles like wind with strength depending on distance. I have included the code i have so far for the double pendulum, it includes a tracer that follows the end of the pendulum with a line, the gravity function will allow the user to create their own lines with some form of control.

```
float r1 = 200;
float r2 = 200;
float m1 = 40;
float m2 = 40;
float a1 = PI/2;
float a2 = PI/2;
float a1_v = 0;
float a2_v = 0;
float g = 1;

float px2 = -1;
float py2 = -1;
float cx, cy;

PGraphics canvas;

void setup() {
  size(1024, 768);
  cx = width/2;
  cy = 200;
  canvas = createGraphics(width, height);
  canvas.beginDraw();
  canvas.background(255);
  canvas.endDraw();
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  imageMode(CORNER);
  image(canvas, 0, 0, width, height);

  float num1 = -g * (2 * m1 + m2) * sin(a1);
  float num2 = -m2 * g * sin(a1-2*a2);
  float num3 = -2*sin(a1-a2)*m2;
  float num4 = a2_v*a2_v*r2+a1_v*a1_v*r1*cos(a1-a2);
  float den = r1 * (2*m1+m2-m2*cos(2*a1-2*a2));
  float a1_a = (num1 + num2 + num3*num4) / den;

  num1 = 2 * sin(a1-a2);
  num2 = (a1_v*a1_v*r1*(m1+m2));
  num3 = g * (m1 + m2) * cos(a1);
  num4 = a2_v*a2_v*r2*m2*cos(a1-a2);
  den = r2 * (2*m1+m2-m2*cos(2*a1-2*a2));
  float a2_a = (num1*(num2+num3+num4)) / den;

  translate(cx, cy);
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(2);

  float x1 = r1 * sin(a1);
  float y1 = r1 * cos(a1);

  float x2 = 0;
  float y2 = 0;

  if(mousePressed){
    x2 = mouseX - cx;
    y2 = mouseY - cy;
  }else{
    x2 = x1 + r2 * sin(a2);
    y2 = y1 + r2 * cos(a2);  
  }

  line(0, 0, x1, y1);
  fill(0);
  ellipse(x1, y1, m1, m1);

  line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  fill(0);
  ellipse(x2, y2, m2, m2);

  a1_v += a1_a;
  a2_v += a2_a;
  a1 += a1_v;
  a2 += a2_v;

  // a1_v *= 0.99;
  // a2_v *= 0.99;

  canvas.beginDraw();
  //canvas.background(0, 1);
  canvas.translate(cx, cy);
  canvas.stroke(0);
  if (frameCount > 1) {
    canvas.line(px2, py2, x2, y2);
   }
  canvas.endDraw();


  px2 = x2;
  py2 = y2;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, be sure to check out the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn yourself a badge. I recommend going through the [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to debug small programs guide](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). This question is very similar your earlier questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54183903/how-to-add-mouse-drag-function-to-double-pendulum) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54291675/how-to-rework-acceleration-formula-for-double-pendulum-with-mouse-interaction)

Comment: The way your question is currently phrased sounds like you're not interesting in understanding the code your using (be if [from a forum](https://hacking.sx/Thread-Double-Pendulum) that doesn't explain the math or not) but instead describe what you'd like to achieve. It almost feels like what you'd like other to achieve for you. I would getting your hands dirty and understanding the code: it will make a much better programmer. Start by changing the values variables at the top and commenting or even better renaming them so they're easier to read/understand (e.g. `radius` for `r`, `mass` for `m`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add mouse drag function to double pendulum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54183903/how-to-add-mouse-drag-function-to-double-pendulum)

Comment: ...after you're renamed the variables focus on the section in `draw()` that defines `num1`, `num2`,`num3`, etc. Start with one variable there at a time and debug/follow it in code: what does it do / how does it affect the simulation ? Once you've got a feel for that it will be much much easier to define a force (vector) that you add the computed force of one ball or the other as you wish. I recommend a bit of Linear Algebra too and [Daniel Shiffman's Vector's chapter](https://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-1-vectors/) and basic trigonometry (sin/cos and polar to cartesian coordinate conversion)

Comment: ...there are even [videos on vectors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWJkvxQXIa8&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6ZwSmtE13iJBcoI-r4y7iEc) and [simulating mass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHWGFXZvD0s). You might actually be able to write you own pendulum simulation from scratch that will be much easier to tweak after you practice the notions in these short videos. Good luck